# How to decode JavaScript files chunk.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

```
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[17],{212:function(e,t,a){"use strict";var r=a(3),l=a(4),o=a(7),n=a(6),c=a(8),s=a(0),i=a.n(s),m=a(18),u=a.n(m),p=a(221),d=a.n(p),g=function(e){function t(){var e,a;Object(r.a)(this,t);for(var l=arguments.length,c=new Array(l),s=0;s<l;s++)c[s]=arguments[s];return(a=Object(o.a)(this,(e=Object(n.a)(t)).call.apply(e,[this].concat(c)))).state={shareButton:!1},a.shareLink=function(e)..
```

file name: `17.d37b3f81.chunk.js`

I am trying to decode these js files. there are many chunk files..

Is there is a way to decode this to back into react understandable code??